# Logical conundrum in automatically installing libraries

Tags: python3

I have a bit of code that attempts to install a library if it doesn't already exist - this is for deployment on many machines so I'm trying to automate as much as possible.

My code looks like this:

```
try:
    import pymssql
except ImportError:
    # weirdly this only works in Windows.  You'll need to find a workaround for Ubuntu
    os.system('python -m pip install pymssql')
    import pymssql
```

the output generated in Ubuntu is:

```
Collecting pymssql
  Downloading pymssql-2.2.7-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (4.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 4.0 MB 1.8 MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pymssql
Successfully installed pymssql-2.2.7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pullFromSQL.py", line 24, in <module>
    import pymssql
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymssql'
```

you can see my conundrum, the install was successful, but I still can't load the library.

If I then run the code again the library loads fine.

Is this just a matter of putting a delay in to wait for some task to take place or is there a more graceful workaround?

Thanks,

DougM

Comment: I think I sow similar behavior on `python3.8` but not on later versions e.g. `python3.10` ... try reloading site packages/system path right after install with e.g. `import site; from importlib import reload; reload(site)`